# How to set parameter for std::map structure in launch file

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! As described in the title, my question is how I could input the parameter for a std::map structure in a roslaunch file, which is needed by a node. I use ros-indigo. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220375/how-to-set-parameter-for-std::map-structure-in-launch-file/) by [mikegao88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22574/mikegao88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the question is rather how to get some configuration from a launch file into the nodes, that you go on to store that information in an `std::map` just an extra.

You most probably want to use the [parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) which is available to you per default when you run ROS.

You can store name-value pairs on the server in a launch file with [the `<param>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) then you can access it in your node as [described in the documentation.](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server). In Brief:

```
ros::param::param<std::string>("default_param", default_param, "default_value");
```

Note that the parameter names are global, but you can set private parameters per node by putting the  tag inside the `<node>` tag:

```
   <node ...>
       <param name="foo" .../>
   </node>
```

Then you need to use "~foo" to access it.

PS: [It is possible to store an entire map with a single name on the parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists), but I know of no way to use that feature with launch files. You will need to specify a parameter for each map element.

PPS:
Also note the convenient [`<rosparam>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) that allows:

```
<rosparam>
 my_parameter_1: 768
 my_parameter_2: 480
</rosparam>
```

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1